# Necromancer without Revival

Tags: support, badges

On my main site, Chemistry.SE, I answered an older question yesterday and have received 5 upvotes  on it - to which, soon after, I earned a Necromancer badge. But, I noticed that I did not receive the Revival badge for the same question.

I am not all that worried about not receiving the Revival badge, just found this occurrence odd.

Is it possible to receive a Necromancer badge without a Revival badge, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and not a bug.

Necromancer doesn't require your post to be the first answer to the question scoring 5, while to get the Revival, your must be the first answerer to get your answer the score of 2.

Example is [your own recent answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24885/mimic-a-volcano-eruption-with-household-chemicals/33617#33617), as you mentioned: you did get Necromancer because got the score of five; however someone answered before you in the February and their answer scored more than 2, that's why you didn't get the Revival.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense - thank you!

Comment: @san Well, welcome :)

Comment: Revival is not for first answer; it's for first answer score 2+, I think